# Continuity by Contradiction

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$. I'm trying to show that $f$ is continuous at $0$ by contradiction.

In order for a function to not be continuous at $0$: There exists an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n} > 0$, $|x_{n} - 0| \leq \delta_n \implies |\sqrt{x_n} - 0| > \epsilon$ where $x_n$ is an element in the domain of $f$.

Suppose $\epsilon = 1$. Then I see that $|\sqrt{x_n}| > 1 \implies x_n > 1$. But I see that $x_n \to 0$ since $\delta_n = \frac{1}{n} \to 0$.

This would be a contradiction because $x_n > 1$ which means that $\{x_n\}$ will never converge to 0.

Could I get some feedback on my proof?

Comment: The negation you want is: $(\exists \varepsilon >0)(\forall \delta_n=\frac1{n})(\exists x_n)$ so that $|x_n-0|<\delta_n$ and $|\sqrt{x_n}-0|>\varepsilon$. You're missing the $\exists x_n$ part.

Comment: It is along the right lines, except for two points: (1) You are missing a quantifiers as in '$\exists x_n$ such that...'. (2) You can't just choose $\epsilon$, you need to use the $\epsilon$ that 'exists'.

Comment: Also, a direct proof would be much simpler, since you can compute an explicit $\delta$ that makes $|\sqrt{x}| < \epsilon$. Generally, constructive proofs are nicer.

Comment: You've only shown that that there can't be such an $\epsilon$ in $[1, \infty)$. You also need to show that there is no such $\epsilon$ in $(0,1)$. The proof can be carried for all cases at once by looking at the first $\delta_n$ such that $\delta_n < \epsilon^2$ (which exists by the Archimedean property).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assume that $f$ is not continuous at 0, here's  what you  would know:

There exists an $\epsilon>0$ such that for every $\delta_n={1\over n}$, there exists an $x_n$ such that $0\le x_n<\delta_n$ and $\sqrt{x_n}\ge\epsilon$.

You *do not* get to choose this $\epsilon$; in particular, you do not know it is equal to $1$. So your argument falls apart here. 
But you can say "Let $\epsilon>0$ be a number satisfying the condition of the preceding  paragraph". You don't know the actual value of $\epsilon$, but you do know it is a fixed, positive number.
 Then, towards deriving a contradiction, what you could do is find a $\delta_n$ such that no number $x_n$ satisfies both  $0\le x_n<\delta_n$ and $\sqrt{x_n}\ge\epsilon$. (Towards this end, consider the square  of $\epsilon$.)

Incidentally, a direct proof would be much neater in my opinion (note that in the suggested argument above, you are essentially proving continuity at 0 directly).